# tinyMCE does not display text in View (migration from CakePHP 1.x to 2.x)

Tags: cakephp, tinymce, migration, cakephp-2.0

I've migrated from CakePHP 1.3 to CakePHP 2.x, but when edit a new tinyMCE does not display text:

*NewsController.php*

```
class NewsController extends AppController {
public $components = array('Auth','RequestHandler');
public $name = 'News';
public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form', 'Tinymce', 'Fck', 'Ajax', 'Text', 'Session');
public $uses = array('News', 'NewsSet', 'Photo', 'Gallery', 'Curse', 'L10n');

public function view($id = null) {

    if (!$id) {
        $this->flash(__('Invalid News', true), array('action'=>'index'));
    }
    //$this->set('news', $this->News->read(null, $id));
    $news = $this->News->read(null, $id);
    $this->set('news', $news);
    $curse = $this->News->NewsSet->Curse->findById($news['NewsSet']['curse_id']);
    $this->set('curse', $curse);
    $block = $this->News->NewsSet->Curse->Block->findById($curse['Curse']['block_id']);
    $this->set('block', $block);
    $idphotos = array();
    foreach ($news['Photo'] as $photo):
        $idphotos[] = $photo['id'];
    endforeach;
    $photos = $this->Photo->find("all", array('conditions' => array('Photo.id' => $idphotos) , 'recursive' => 1));
    $this->set('photos', $photos);
    $tree = $this->navTree($news['NewsSet']['id'], $news['NewsSet']['curse_id']);
    $this->set('tree', $tree);
}}
```

*View/News/edit.ctp*

```
echo $this->tinymce->input('body', array('label'=>'Texte', 'rows'=>30, 'cols'=>30), array( 
     'theme' => 'advanced',          
     /*'valid_elements' => "strong/b,em/i,p,br,u/span",*/ /* Definit al .js de Tinymce*/
     'invalid_elements' => "div",
    "plugins" => "safari,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",
      "theme_advanced_buttons1" => "newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
    "theme_advanced_buttons2"=> "bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,image,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor,advhr,|,print,|fullscreen",
    "theme_advanced_buttons3" => "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,tablecontrols",
    //theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak",
    "theme_advanced_toolbar_location" => "top",
     "theme_advanced_toolbar_align" => "left",
     "theme_advanced_statusbar_location" => "bottom",
     "theme_advanced_resizing" => true,
 "entity_encoding" => "raw",
    ));
    echo $this->form->input('title', array('label'=>'Títol'));
echo $this->form->input('subtitle', array('label'=>'Subtítol'));
```

Well, "tinyMCE" does work, loading the editor, but does not load the text.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no `tinymce` helper in the core CakePHP code. Is this a helper you've developed yourself or a third-party plugin? Does it support CakePHP 2.x? Is the field populated in the source code?

Comment: debug the custom helper `tinymce` that you have developed